# Where to store node / express environment variables?

Tags: node.js, express, config, environment

I am new to node/express and was wondering

1. where should I store environment variables?
2. where I should store config files?
3. if there's an example out there on how to configure the config file?

Thanks!!

Comment: 1. you don't, they're set on the environment. 2. in a config folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can store your config files under config dir and load them based on your requirement.
2. As for environment variables, if you mean the variables passed during run time execution; then I believe you can directly access them under your project. If you mean to store project level information then you can use something like project.json and also have env variables in it.
3. You can use this project as [reference](https://github.com/pilwon/ultimate-seed) for both the tasks.